# i want to disable textbox on click of checkbox. checkboxes are dynamic

Tags: php, jquery

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("input:checkbox").click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                if (id) {
                    $("#txtPassportNumber").removeAttr("disabled");
                    $("#txtPassportNumber").focus();
                }
            } else {
                $("#txtPassportNumber").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my jquery code am getting one textbox enabled by this

```
<label for="chkPassport">
    <?php
    $select_size = $common->select('size_m', '');
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($select_size as $sizes) {
        $s = $sizes['sizename'];
        ?>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkPassport<?php echo $s; ?>" class="current"/>
        <?php echo $sizes['sizename']; ?>
    </label>
    qty:
    <input type="text" id="txtPassportNumber<?php echo $i;?>"  disabled="disabled" class="current<?php echo $s; ?>"/>
    <br/>
    <?php
    $i++;
}
?>
```

I am not getting id of textbox even i am giving

`id="txtPassportNumber<?php $i; ?>"`

I am having 5 sizes and on every size i want to add qty when i click S i want to enable its textbox when i click M its textbox must enable.I am getting one textbox enabled onclick of size S because it is not taking my id there.Help me for this

Comment: try after `echo $i` in php `id="txtPassportNumber<?php echo $i;?>"`

Comment: Try the following instead, `id="txtPassportNumber<?=$i?>"`

Comment: It is taking id of <input type="checkbox" id="chkPassport<?php echo $s;?>" class="current"/> 
i want it to take id  of <input type="text" id="txtPassportNumber"  disabled="disabled" class="current<?php echo $s;?>"/>
so that i can make my textbox enabled

Comment: try with `.on('click'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking to solve the selection problem so here is a small 'JQuery' code.

I wonted to explain what I've done with the below code. In your code you were trying to use the ID of the element you wanted to change. The problem is ID's need to be unique for each element if you have the same ID for all then all those elements will be considered as one.

Also you were trying to assign a number to the ID (`id="txtPassportNumber<?php echo $i;?>"`) which makes it double hard to identify.

So what I did in my code is to move the listener from ID to class which makes it easier and free up the ID for you to do what ever you want with it. In the script the `JQuery` listens to see if there's a click event on the *.sizeChk* class if it's true then it checks if the click event is to check the check box or not. Then if the check box is checked then it looks for the *input* `.next()` to the checked check box.

I used `.next()` because the `input` is on to the right hand side if the `input` was to the left hand side you can use `.prev()`. After finding the *input* next to the check box it applies the `.prop()`. I didn't use `.attr()` because it's old and not encouraged by `JQuery` it self.

You only have to keep the class in tact and you can use the same class to any other check box to get the same function on those elements.

***A side note:*** It's best you read up on `JQuery` a little bit more.

**Older Answer which match the description.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sizeChk').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).next("input").prop('disabled', false).focus();
    } else {
      $(this).next("input").prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" class="sizeChk" />Small:
<input type="text" id="txt1" class="sizeTxt" disabled/><br><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk2" class="sizeChk" />Medium:
<input type="text" id="txt2" class="sizeTxt" disabled/><br><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk3" class="sizeChk" />Larg:
<input type="text" id="txt3" class="sizeTxt" disabled/><br><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk4" class="sizeChk" />xLarg:
<input type="text" id="txt4" class="sizeTxt" disabled/><br><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk5" class="sizeChk" />xxLarg:
<input type="text" id="txt5" class="sizeTxt" disabled/>
```

**New updated code**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sizeChk').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).closest('.sizeGroup').find('input[type=text]').prop('disabled', false).focus();
    } else {
      $(this).closest('.sizeGroup').find('input[type=text]').prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sizeGroup">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" class="sizeChk" />Small:<br>
  <input type="text" id="txt1" class="sizeTxt" disabled/><br><br>
</div>
<div class="sizeGroup">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" class="sizeChk" />Medium:<br>
  <input type="text" id="txt2" class="sizeTxt" disabled/><br><br>
</div>
<div class="sizeGroup">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk3" class="sizeChk" />Larg:<br>
  <input type="text" id="txt3" class="sizeTxt" disabled/><br><br>
</div>
<div class="sizeGroup">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk4" class="sizeChk" />xLarg:<br>
  <input type="text" id="txt4" class="sizeTxt" disabled/><br><br>
</div>
```

Hope this help.

Here is the old [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sadaruwan12/avuLntj1/2/).

Here is the updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avuLntj1/7/)

Comment: @shikha happy to here it worked for you I just up dated my answer with a description on the function of the `JQuery`.

Comment: Good explanation but in case if i apply <br> after input than .next will not work what's the solution for it.

Comment: Well `.next()` is only looking for `input` not `<br>` in my snippet and in fiddle I have used `<br>` with out any issue.

Comment: yea It is more accurate answer Thanks @Sand :)